# Quickly compute added and removed lines

Tags: java, algorithms, file-handling

I'm trying to compare two text files. I want to compute how many lines were added and removed. Basically what `git diff --stat` is doing. Bonus points for not having to store the entire file contents in memory.

The approach I'm currently having in mind is:

1. read each line of the old file
2. compute a hash (probably MD5 or SHA-1) for each line
3. store the hashes in a set
4. do the same for each line in the new file
5. every hash from the old file set that's missing in the new file set was removed
6. every hash from the new file set that's missing in the old file set was added

I'll probably want to exclude empty and all white space lines. There is a small issue with duplicated lines. This can either be solved by additionally storing how often a hash appears or comparing the number of lines in the old and new file and adjust either the added or removed lines so that the numbers add up.

Do you see room for improvements or a better approach?

**Edit**

I'm currently using Java and the SVNKit library.

Comment: It seems you do not to not care for the order of lines - is that intentional?

Comment: Right, I don't care about the order.

Comment: Actually, if you don't care about the order, your algorithm outline seems to be the standard approach for solving this problem. Simple to implement, and as fast as it can be. Note that using hashes only, without comparing the original data, leaves you with a slight risk of hash collisions of non-identical lines. Of course, if you have really big files to process, you may reach memory limits.

Comment: So if I change one letter in a line your algorithm counts 1 added and 1 removed line.

Comment: Why would you use hashes instead of directly comparing lines? Calculating a hash is not free.

Comment: Yeah but neither is storing the lines, and particularly in Java, String's have a cheap builtin `hash()` method that returns an int (4 bytes), as opposed to storing maybe 40 bytes for each line if you're storing the actual lines.

Comment: Won't such a small hash have a very high chance of collision? If you take like a standard md5 hash, you're already storing 16 bytes/line.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is something quite common among diff tools, why not use a tried-and-tested diff library to do the work efficiently instead of rolling out your own code?

Searching for "diff library" or "diff tools" with the name of the language would provide some easier ways.

Comment: I'm currently parsing the output of `svn diff`. But I'm not happy with the performance, I'm doing it over the entire repository. Since I actually need less information than `svn diff` I figured there must be a quicker way to do it.

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall The answer does not suggest using the `diff` in a separate process, but rather taking an existing `diff` *library*, and embedding it in your code. This will improve performance, because no new process would be created for each pair of files that you are `diff`-fing.

Comment: I'm already calling `svn diff` in-process.

Comment: but you are creating an sub-process and let svn diff do unnecessary work. a library is something you use natively inside your program code. example is http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall: I don't know if the separate process is the bottleneck in your case. But using **SVN** diff does not seem to make much sense here, at least not from the requirements you told us. Or are your textfiles really already stored in a subversion repository? Or, in other words, why the heck don't you use the standard diff (without SVN) tool?

Comment: @JanPrieser I'm calling the diff code of a Subversion library in-process. I'm not forking a new process.

Comment: @DocBrown standard diff tool doesn't really do what I need. I only want to know how many lines were added or removed. I don't care where or what they are. I didn't see a way to configure diff to do exactly that. In the end I would end up parsing the output just like with Subversion.

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall What language is your code in? If you add that information to your question, you may get better answers.

And yes, as others have stated above, my answer was to use a `diff` library within the application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `diffstat` command (usually in the `diffstat` package in most Linux distros), that can help you achieve this:

```
svn diff | diffstat
```

This outputs more or less the same as `git diff --stat`

If this is not an option for you, then maybe a good alternative is to parse the output of `svn diff`: count the lines starting with `+` and `-`, keep in mind that for each affected files there will be lines starting with `+++` and `---`.

Answer (score 0):

why not do this:

1. read each line of the old file
2. there's no 2
3. store the **lines** in a set
4. do the same for each line in the new file
5. every **line** from the old file set that's missing in the new file set was removed
6. every **line** from the new file set that's missing in the old file set was added

I don't see any need to calculate hashes, if you're going to compare things you might as well compare actual lines.